# how to make this html responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

i am new in the Website developement. i tried to responsive this code..but its not working.
i just wants to make this page responsive.
i am trying this webpage to be responsive on mobile , tablet , laptop view 
this is my html code

```css
body{background-color:black}

.main{ margin:0 auto; padding:0px;background-color:white;font-family:Arial,Helentica;font-size:12px; color:#000;width:935px;background-color:white}

.header{width:814px;height:123px;padding:65px 0px 0px 120px;font-size:12px; color:black;font-family:Arial;background-color:white}

.logo1{float:left;padding-right:50px;}

.logo2{float:right;padding-right:50px}

.text1{float:left;text-align:center;font-size:20px;color:brown}

.navbar{float:left;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:gray;height:30px;position:absolute;width:934px}

.navbar ul{ display:inline; list-style:none;}

.navbar li{float:left;text-align:center;font:normal bold 12px/2.5em Arial,verdana;text-decoration:none;}

.navbar ul li a{ padding:0 20px 0 20px; border-left:1px solid black;text-decoration:none;color:white;display:block-line;height:50px;}

.navbar li:hover, a:hover {background-color:black;}

.navbar li ul  {display: none; height: auto;margin: 0;padding:0}

.navbar li ul   {position:absolute;width:100%;left:0}
                
.navbar li:hover ul {display: block}
                        
.navbar li ul li {background-color:gray;border:1px solid black}
    
.navbar li ul li a:hover{background-color:black;}

#mid-wraper{width:934px; margin:0 auto; padding:0px;}

#mid-wraper-inner{width:934px; float:left; background-color:white}

#left-wraper{width:296px; float:left; bacground-color:white}

#left-wraper-top{width:296px; background:white; padding:14px 0px 12px 0px; float:left;}

#video{width:270px; float:left; padding:1px 0px 10px 15px; color:#fff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;background-color:white}

.link{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; text-align:right;}

.link:hover{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; text-align:right;}

.link2{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#bc4105; text-decoration:none; text-align:right;}

.link2:hover{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#bc4105; text-decoration:none; text-align:right;}

#right-wraper{width:596px; float:left; padding:15px 0px 0px 25px;}

.right-part{width:596px; float:left;}

#foter{width:934px; margin:0 auto; padding:0px; color:#999999; }

#foter-inner{width:934px; float:left; padding:10px 0px;}

.footer-link{color:#999999; text-decoration:none; padding:0px 5px;}

.footer-link:hover{color:#999999; text-decoration:none; padding:0px 5px;}



This is my html
i have bootstrap and i tried a lot but its getting messy
please help
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" >
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <style>

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        background-color:black;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color:black;
    }
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
 
           <div class="main">
           
        <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo1"><img src="images/logo1.jpg" alt="" height="100" width="100"></div>
                    <div class="text1"><strong>AGNIHOTRI COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING,<br>WARDHA</strong>
        <br><div style="float:left;text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:brown;padding-left:50px">(Near Bypass Highway,Nagthana Road Sindi(Meghe))<br>Email:ace@agnihotri.org
        <br>Phone:07152-250152
        </div> </div>
                    <div class="logo2"><img src="images/12.png" alt="" height="100" width="100"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="navbar">
         <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="governance.html">Governance</a></li>
      <li><a href="campus.html">Campus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Department</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Basic Science</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Machanical Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Civil Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="comp.html">Computer science & Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Electronics & Communication Engineering</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">M.Tech(computer science & Engg.)</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">M.Tech(Electronics)</a></li>
                     </ul> </li>
      <li><a href="addmission.html">Addmission</a></li>
                  <li><a href="facility.html">Facility</a></li>
      <li><a href="download.html">Download</a></li>
      <li><a href="place.html">Placement</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallary.html">Gallary</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
     
            <div class="middle">
               <div class="mid-wrapper">
                <img src="images/3.jpg" width="934px" height="250px"</div>
 
           </div>
    
                         <div id="mid-wraper">
                         <div id="mid-wraper-inner">
                         <div id="left-wraper">
                         <div id="left-wraper-top">
                         <div
                             style="margin: 0px;width: 256px; float: left; display: block;background-color:white;padding-left:20px">
        <h2 style="background-color:brown;text-align:center;color:white">News</h2>
                             <marquee direction="up"><b><p style="text-align:center">ALL THE BEST STUDENTS <br>FOR UNIVERSITY EXAM:</p><b><br>
                 <p style="color:blue;text-align:center">University Summer 2018<br> Exam Timetables<br> Are Available In<br> The Download Section: </marquee></p>
                          </div>

                         </div>
                         <div id="video">
                         <h2 style="background-color:brown;text-align:center;color:white">Video</h2>
                            <video controls autoplay width="300px" height="100px" >
           <source src="images/college.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           </video>

                          </div>
        <div style="padding-left:30px">
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" width="250px" height="150px" ></div>
                         </div>
                        
                     <div id="right-wraper">
                           <div class="right-part">
                           <h2 style="background-color:brown;text-align:center;color:white">Welcome to Agnihotri College Of Engineering</h2>
        
                           <div style="padding: 10px 0px; width: 596px; float: left;background-color:white">
         In this angnihotri collge of  engineering is a very big collge..they have many facilities for student and teacher staff..so please check my wesite to many student..i am hope so very nice collge..
         <br><br>
                             <div style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:150px;height:20px;text-align:center">Our Vision</div>
         <br>
        To develop globally competent, efficient learner and community oriented model of Engineering education.
                   <br><br>
               <div style="background-color:brown;color:white;width:150px;height:20px;text-align:center">Our Misson</div>
          <br>
                        To create value added, competent and research oriented trained Engineering professionals for sustainable development of the society.
         <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>

                      <div class="right-part" style="padding: 10px 0px;">
                      <div style="width: 290px; float: left;">
                      <h2 style="background-color:brown;color:white;text-align:center">President's Message</h2>
                        <div style="padding-left:90px"><img src="images/presi.gif" alt="" width="100px" height="70px"></div>
      <br>
                       <div
                            style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); width: 289px; float: left; padding-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
       I feel proud and happy to introduce to you ACE and welcome you to this prestigious institution, ACE is managing unprecedented growth through proliferation of a variety of knowledge institutes as part
                            <br>
                            <a href="governance.html" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a></div>
                      </div>
                      <div style="width: 270px; float: right; padding-right: 10px;">
                     <h2 style="background-color:brown;text-align:center;color:white">Scretory's Message</span></h2>
       <div style="padding-left:90px"><img src="images/secre.gif" alt="" width="100px" height="70px"></div>
      <br>
                       <div
                           style="width: 269px; float: left; padding-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
         Our vision is to develop a strong, enthusiastic manpower from Engineering Stream with an excellent academic standing of a global level. The globalization has created many challenges of Competition, training and placem
                           <br>
                       <a href="governance.html" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a></div>
                       </div>
         <div style="width: 500px; float: left;">
                      <h2 style="background-color:brown;color:white;text-align:center">Principle's Message</h2>

                       <div
                            style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); width: 550px; float: left; padding-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
       Education is an essential human virtue, necessity for society and basis of good life. Addison says-"What sculpture is to a block of marble, education is to the soul".

                            <a href="governance.html" class="link2" style="float: right;">read more</a></div>
                      </div>
                       </div>
                       </div>
                       </div>
                       </div>
                       <div id="foter">
                       <div id="foter-inner">
<p
 style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 550px; float: left; display: block;"><a
 href="#" class="footer-link">Home</a> <a href="#" class="footer-link">About
us</a> <a href="#" class="footer-link">Recent articles</a> <a href="#"
 class="footer-link">Email</a> <a href="#" class="footer-link">Resources</a>
<a href="#" class="footer-link">Links</a></p>
<p
 style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 200px; float: right; text-align: right; display: block;">&copy;
Designed by <a class="footer-link" target="_blank"
 href="http://www.htmltemplates.net/">htmltemplates.net</a></p>
</div>
</div>
     
     
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

please someone help to get this page responsive
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap grid layout like container,col-md,col-xs,col-sm and in styles give  width:% don't use px

for [bootstrap reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Yes @akshadaRohokale, its possible use media queries

Answer (score 0):

I think, in this case, it's better to work upwards with breakpoints.

For example, on mobile you want width 100%. No media query needed and start with basic behaviour.

```
div.item {
    width: 100%; // div is 100% by default, so actually not needed
    background-color: #000;
}
```

For tablets and upwards you might want to add exceptions: width 50%, floating, and grey background:

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
    // tablet
    .item {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        background: #ccc;
    }
}
```

And so on...

```
@media(min-width: 992px) {
    .item {
        // ....
    }
}

@media(min-width: 1200px) {
    // desktop
    .item {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the div tag  **< div class="maintag">** below the body tag and close it above body tag 
eg:

.
.
.

then use css use .maintag{margin-left="10px";margin-right="10px"}